# Архитектура в WPF MVVM + DI. Как передавать данные в дочерние вью модели?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, di

Сразу вопрос, а потом описание. Как при резолве сервиса из контейнера передавать данные?
Или с моей архитектурой изначально что-то не так?

У меня есть модель в БД, по структуре деревья. При запуске приложения нужно создать соответствующие `ViewModel`. Пока это работает так. В App вызывается асинхронный метод `MainViewModel.InitAppData()` для получения данных и создания вью моделей и экран загрузки сменяется готовой вьюшкой.

Класс `App`

```
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    await AppHost!.StartAsync();

    var mainWindow = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    var mainVM = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>();
    mainWindow.DataContext = mainVM;
    mainWindow.Show();

    mainVM.InitAppData();
}
```

Класс `MainViewModel`

```
internal class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    readonly IServiceProvider? _serviceProvider;
    public MainViewModel(IServiceProvider? serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    bool _isDataLoaded = false;
    public async void InitAppData()
    {
        using var dbContext = _serviceProvider?.GetRequiredService<MainDbContext>();
        if (dbContext == null) return; //TODO: error handling
        var skills = await dbContext.GetTreesAsync();

        SkillTreeUC = new SkillTreeUC();
        _skillTreeVM = new SkillTreeViewModel(skills);
        SkillTreeUC.DataContext = _skillTreeVM;


        _isDataLoaded = true;
    }

    UserControl _skillTreeUC = new LoadingUC();
    public UserControl SkillTreeUC
    {
        get => _skillTreeUC;
        set
        {
            _skillTreeUC = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SkillTreeUC));
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `SkillTreeViewModel`

```
internal class SkillTreeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    /*Вот тут в конструктор передается модель, которая зависит от 
    предыдущей
    Тут мне нужно зарезолвить сервис и прокинуть в него эту модель
    И вот как добавить сервис в контейнер, оставив конструктору
    место для пользовательского свойства*/
    public SkillTreeViewModel(List<Skill> skills)//Тут корни деревьев
    {
        foreach(Skill skill in skills)
        {
            SkillVMs.Add(new(skill));
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel> SkillVMs { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Класс `SkillViewModel`

```
internal class SkillViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public SkillViewModel(Skill skill)
    {
        Name = skill.Name;
        Description = skill.Description ?? String.Empty; ;
        Notes = skill.Notes ?? String.Empty;
        var chilldren = skill.Children ?? new();
        foreach (var child in chilldren)
        {
            SkillVMs.Add(new(child));
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<SkillViewModel> SkillVMs = new();
}
```

И все бы замечательно, но мне нужно использовать dbContext в дочерних моделях, и я понял что игнорирую существование DI контейнера. Но при первой инициализации мне нужно передавать в каждую дочернюю вью модель соответствующую модель.

Comment: Когда вы используете контейнер - у вас не должно быть в коде каких-либо `= new()`, ибо за вас инициализирует все сам контейнер. Добавьте в контейнер все ваши VM, M слои, заберите оттуда главное окно и главную VM, все, дальше контейнер будет сам подставлять нужные типы, вам достаточно будет из попросить. Что касается `SkillTreeViewModel(List<Skill> skills)` - почему вы просите уже готовые данные снаружи, а не объект базы, чтобы эти данные уже внутри попросить? Кто зависит от базы, класс `App`, или `SkillTreeViewModel`? Я думаю 2-е, ну так почему тогда 1-й просит данные из базы?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я догадываюсь что не должно быть `new()`, но что-то не пойму куда логику инициализации запихнуть. Прошу данные снаружи потому что асинхронных конструкторов не бывает. У меня ведь меняется вьюшка с загрузочной на настоящую., чтобы UI не висел во время загрузки данных из базы. И ведь каждая следующая ViewModel зависит от предыдущей. Она сама не знает что ей просить у базы. И это же множественные запросы, а я достаю за раз все узлы дерева. У меня от этих деревьев уже голова кружится. Сейчас еще подумаю, пока не понял.

Comment: Ваша проблема сейчас в том, что у вас классы и методы отвечают не за свои обязанности (нарушение SRP из SOLID), например `InitAppData` отвечает вдруг за базу, когда она ему, по сути, не нужна, но нужна у `SkillTreeViewModel`. Также ваша проблема в том, что вы используете такие вещи как "конструктор" не просто для инициализации, а еще и для загрузки, когда это не его обязанности. Я на вашем месте сделал бы след.: `public SkillTreeViewModel(MainDbContext db) => _dbContext = db;` далее `public async Task Load(){ ... await dbContext.GetTreesAsync(); }`. Ну и вызов этого метода в `InitAppData()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я немного добавил кода чтобы было все очевиднее. `InitAppData()` прокинуть на два уровня в `SkillTreeViewModel`? Ок, сделаю. А данные то как прокинуть вглубь дерева `TreeViewModel` чтобы это не нарушало концепцию DI? Мне надо что-то вроде `_serviceProvider?.GetRequiredService<TreeViewModel>([модель для инициализации]);`. Даже если бы я данные из контекста БД доставал, как ей дать понять к какой модели она относится? К какому конкретно инстансу, ну Вы поняли.

Comment: А что такое `TreeViewModel`? Логика этого класса в чем? Вот смотрите, простой пример с выводом информации о директории: У нас есть Model - некий класс, который имеет методы по типу получения списка директорий и информации о них (вес, когда была создана и др.). Далее у нас есть ViewModel слой - это некий слой, который запрашивает данные из Model и на их основе стоит новую структуру данных, необходимых лишь для привязки. Ну и View слой - кнопочки, `TreeView` и так далее.

Comment: Теперь вопрос: что нам может понадобиться в дальнейшем, в других классах? Наверно Model (захотим получить список папок), а также главная ViewModel (захотим вызвать ее методы из другой VM). Ок, но нужна-ли нам VM самого дерева папок, которую строит главная VM? Я думаю, нет, ибо это лишь данные для отображения, не более. Вот также и у вас, есть Model, есть ViewModel (с ее мелкими VM), и есть View. Нужно-ли вам хранить `TreeViewModel` в контейнере? Нужен-ли он будет дальше, в другом месте, или это логика конкретной VM, которая только там и должна оставаться? Смысл хранить `TreeViewModel` в DI?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  `TreeViewModel` это для встраиваемого UI блока, просто как визуальный контейнер. А в `SkillViewModel` данные для кадого элемента дерева, опять же для удобства разбиения по визуальным блокам.

Comment: Ну вот определитесь, место `TreeViewModel` в DI или нет. Ведь DI - это коллекция типов, которые вы постоянно вызываете в разных местах (всякие сервисы, модели, и др. классы). Если вы не собираетесь `TreeViewModel` вызывать за пределами класса, где он находится, то и в DI ему делать нечего.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А `TreeViewModel ` и так не в контейнере, она нужна один раз. Хотя она будет, раз в ней нужен IServiceProvider. Я кажется придумал, уже делаю. Я прокину в DI контейнер фабрику для `SkillViewModel`, которая и будет резолвить IServiceProvider и пропихивать его в `SkillViewModel`, тогда в метод фабрики `Create()` я могу закидывать инстансы модели `Skill`. А `SkillViewModel`в DI вообще не будет, но в ней будет провайдер автоматически. Хотелось бы, конечно, любые сервисы сразу в конструктор закидывать `SkillViewModel`, но других идей у меня пока нет.

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема хранить ссылку на ваш `_serviceProvider`? Не очень хорошо, но будет работать. Если хочется лучше - то передавайте ваш сервис `MainDbContext`, но сделайте в нем метод который будет вызывать **Dispose** не самого сервиса, а внутри метода, таким образом вам не придется думать о `using` для сервиса, да и это странно очень как по мне т.к. это класс для управления БД. Я бы сделал таким образом:

Создал класс у которого была бы зависимости от контекста базы данных либо какая-либо lazy ссылка на него. В этом классе были бы методы которые обращаются к базе данных и тут мы приходим к известному паттеру **Репозиторий**...

Comment: Не по Фен-Шую это. Зачем тогда DI контейнер нужен?)

Comment: @Saint по опыту скажу, что DI контейнер в больших wpf приложениях плохо работает. Он идеален для Web технологий, а зависимости хоть и нужно получать через конструктор, но упираться именно чтобы DI все делал - сложно да и не всегда нужно. Все же DI контейнер - его идея и суть это не просто зависимости, а их время жизни в контексте, а вот в wpf кроме как singleton/static этот DI больше никак и не используется, отсюда и просится моя идея. А вообще если человеку нужно работать с БД - то это всегда Репозиторий если это EF либо кастомный сложный свой класс...

Comment: Я сделал фабрику `SkillViewModelFactory` и запихнул в контейнер. Ей передаю в конструкторе `IServiceProvider`, а она создает `SkillViewModel` и передает `IServiceProvider` уже ей. В итоге делаю так. `var factory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SkillViewModelFactory>()`, а потом `factory.Create(skill)`. А там конструктор `SkillViewModel(IServiceProvider provider, Skill skill)`. Ну а так да, использование контейнера в таком приложении выглядит примитивным, но зато не надо прокидывать кучу параметров через всю структуру.

Answer (score 0):

Я лично использую так называемый VM-локатор.

```
 public class VM_Locator
    {
        public VM_Locator()
        {

        }

        public static IServiceScope scope;

        public VM_Window1 VM_Window1 => App.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<VM_Window1 >();
        public VM_Window2 VM_Window2 => App.Host.Services.GetRequiredService<VM_Window2 >();


        public static void Init()
        {
            scope?.Dispose();
            scope = App.Host.Services.CreateScope();
        }

        public VM_UserControl1 VM_UserControl1 => scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VM_UserControl1 >();
        public VM_UserControl2 VM_UserControl2 => scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VM_UserControl2 >();
        public VM_UserControl3 VM_UserControl3 => scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VM_UserControl3 >();        
    }
```

Метод Init вызываю в OnStartup и при каждом открытии нового окна.
Внутри любой VM могу обратиться к любому свойству или методу любой другой VM т.о.:

```
VM_Locator.scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<"нужная мне VM">()."нужное мне св-во";
```

Данный локатор внесен в ресурсы app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <vm:VM_Locator x:Key="Locator" />
    </Application.Resources>
```

И DataContext задаю в коде xaml вопреки распространённому здесь мнению, что так делать не нужно.

```
DataContext="{Binding "нужная мне VM", Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Comment: Я тут вчера осознал что строил эскалатор для двух ступенек)) Когда объекты однотипные, то один раз можно и просто в конструктор закинуть. Но вообще я фабрику сделал и через нее закидываю данные, саму фабрику в контейнер и там достаю IServiceProvider. Одним словом это просто обертка, которая при создании инстанса добавляет сервисы из контейнера. Ваш дизайн выглядит удобно, но опять же как данные при резолве передавать из внешней VM во вложенную?